# Copy data from cell in selected row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that pops up every time information is put in column H. You enter in some info, and it populates sheet 2 with that info. I've already got it set to count the last row and everything.
After you hit enter, excel selects the cell below whatever cell in column H you entered information. I need to capture the information in the cells of column A and D in the same row you entered the information in column H, and put that, along with the userform info, in a row in sheet 2. Picture:
[image]

Any help would be great!

Thank you!

Edit: Added code from feedback.

Added global variables.

`Public Range1 As Range
Public Range2 As Range`

and code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

`If Target.Column = "8" Then
        Set Range1 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1)
        Set Range2 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 4) 'lot
        Set Range3 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 8) 'qty used
Reconcile.Show
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub`

Excel is not recognizing Me.Cells. It says, " Method or data member not found"

Comment: Please show us the code you've written thus far or at least your research, this is not a coding service.

Comment: Yes, it really doesn't make much sense unless we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Premise being you already hook into the `Worksheet_Change()`-event to show the userform (which I think you do, since it shows "whenever someone enters information into column H), you can store the values in variables as follows:

Create a separate module for global variables:

```
Public Range1 as Range
Public Range2 as Range
```

Next, in the Worksheet in which you enter the values in column H:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 8
        Set Range1 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1)
        Set Range2 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 2)
        UserForm1.Show 'Do the rest from there
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, if the rest of your script is executed from within the userform or anywhere else, you will still have access to all the information in said cells through Range1 and Range2.

Comment: But why the global variables,can't you just call the form, then in the same routine, gather the data from column a,d and h based on the target row and paste that to sheet 2? As far as I can deduce OP doesn't require the data to be used in the userform.

Comment: @SilentRevolution You could, but since OP is asking how to "capture the information in the cells of column A and D" (which might be any cell property) my initial advice would be "Stick into Range variable". However, as you already commented on OP his question is very vague thus there might be more elegant solutions depending on the exact scenario.

Comment: Yeah, it's really hard to share information with you all since this is for my work. The data from the columns is not used in the userform. I hadn't thought about creating global variables. This should work really well! Thank you!

Comment: I can't get excel to recognize the Me.Cells code. I get the "Method or data member not found" error. I tried "Thisworkbook" and it's still broke. 
Also, the userform will not show if the event is Worksheet_Change. It only works on Workbook_SheetChange. Don't know if that matters. 
This is what I tried based on your feedback:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = "8" Then
        Set Range1 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1)
        Set Range2 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 4) 'lot
        Set Range3 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 8) 'qty used
Reconcile.Show
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

Comment: @micah lankford that code should be placed in the worksheet, not the workbook module. Cells is a worksheet-property.